# How can I display records in multiple tables dynamically using repeater or datalist control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, repeater, datalist

What I would like to do is show the records I get in datatable in different HTML tables. The records in the datatable have 3 columns and I can have a max of 6 records.

The datatable I am getting from the database is as follows:

```
Name   Age
-----------  
XYZ    30

XY1    31

XY2    32

XY3    33
```

And I want to show the records in the following way:

```
Name   Age   Name   Age
-----------------------
XYZ    30    XY1    31

Name   Age   Name   Age
-----------------------     
XY2    32    XY3    33


Total Strength of employees : 4
```

What I am currently doing is as follows (although this is not what I want, but have tried):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptNCode" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RptNcode_ItemCommand" 
  OnItemDataBound="RptNCode_ItemDataBound" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color: #507CD1; color: 
    White; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; height: 20px">
            <td style="color: White;">
                Sr.No
            </td>
            <td style="color: White; text-align: left">
                Name
            </td>
            <td style="color: White; text-align: right">
                 Age 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
   <tr style="background-color: #ffffff; height: 20px; font-family: Arial">

            <td align="left" style="font-size: 15;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNCode" ForeColor="#336699" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="NCode"></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="font-size: 15; text-align: right;">
                <%#  Eval("Age")%>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #ffffff; height: 20px; font-family: Arial">

            <td align="left" style="font-size: 15;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNCode" ForeColor="#336699" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="NCode"></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="font-size: 15; text-align: right;">
                <%#  Eval("Age")%>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <tr>

            <td align="right" height="40px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#336699"></asp:Label>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I know this is not correct but it is what I have done so far. Is what I am trying to do possible or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually pretty close with what you have now. The trick is when you close off your table rows. Try something more like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptNCode" runat="server"
    OnItemCommand="RptNcode_ItemCommand" 
    OnItemDataBound="RptNCode_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Age
            </td>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Age
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Age") %>
            </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>                
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Age") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>            
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Notice how the `AlternatingItemTemplate` keeps the same table row going for another two columns, placing the next record in your datatable on the same row. Then when it reaches the `ItemTemplate` again, it adds another row of header information and starts all over again.

Comment: Great...!! this is what i actually wanted. Hey brother can you please tell me the way to make the name as Link button. actually i am binding another repeater on the click of it. And the total number of employees count in the last of it. Thank you.

Comment: What you have in your code above for the LinkButton looks correct already. Is that not what you want?